# Окно переменной длины и размещение контролов

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, winforms

Допустим, нужно создать окно с тестовыми вопросами. Неизвестно, какой длины будет окно. Как добавлять в такое окно элементы? Вроде с формой не поработаешь. В Qt есть менеджеры компоновки. Там просто добавляешь элементы. В С# есть что-нибудь подобное? Как в таком случае организовать добавление элементов окна?

UPD: Черт, простите, моя вина. Я пишу на WinForms и там уже относительно большой проект написан. Эти вопросы являются частью проекта, которую я оставил для реализации на потом. Так что решения WPF не требуются, хотя все равно спасибо за них, в будущем почитаю про них.

Comment: Для автоматического вычисления размеров (как и для любого нетривиального layout'а) вам по сути нужен WPF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вы используете WinForms, изучайте:

- Свойства:

  - Control.Anchor
  - Control.Dock
  - Control.Margin
  - Control.Padding
- Классы:

  - TableLayoutPanel
  - FlowLayoutPanel
  - SplitterPanel
- См.:

  - [Windows Forms Layout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951306.aspx)

Если вы используете WPF, изучайте:

- Свойства:

  - FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment
  - FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment
  - FrameworkElement.Margin
  - FrameworkElement.Padding
- Классы:

  - Grid
  - DockPanel
  - StackPanel
  - WrapPanel
  - Canvas
- См.:

  - [Layout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx)
  - [Alignment, Margins, and Padding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709.aspx)

В целом, WPF даёт больше свободы для дизайна, поэтому, если вам требуется сложная логика размещения контролов, рекомендуется использовать его. Ну и WPF — более современная и передовая библиотека, лучше поддерживает современные возможности и всё такое.

Answer (score 2):

На мой вкус, правильное решение (на WPF) такое:

1. Список вопросов лежит в вашей VM, в `ObservableCollection<QuestionVM>`.
2. На уровне View используется `ItemsControl`, у которого `ItemsSource` есть `Binding` на список вопросов.
3. Для управления видом отдельного вопроса используйте `ItemTemplate`.

Добавление элемента сводится теперь к модификации коллекции вопросов. View обновится автоматически. Пусть машина работает за вас!